# Git error on untouched repo: Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge

Tags: git, production-environment, git-commit, git-pull

Today I pushed 5 commits to one of my projects, then on the server I pulled the updates, everything was fine. 
After a few hours pushing then pulling on the webserver again and git throws:

`error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    storage/.DS_Store
    storage/app/.DS_Store
    storage/app/public/.DS_Store
    storage/app/public/css/admin.css
    storage/app/public/css/master.css
    storage/app/public/img/.DS_Store
    storage/app/public/img/products/77/textures/black.png
    storage/app/public/img/slider/image1.jpg
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.`

no one edited these files on the production server in the meantime, then why is git complaining? Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: .DS_Store files are auto generated

Comment: please add output of `git status`

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, I ended up stashing stuff for now, as again happens I gonna post `git status`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your repository on your server may be out of sync.

Can you you a git status on your server and see what it says. 
Also it might be a good idea to do a git status -b to make sure you are on your production branch.

Comment: It might be, but the OP just needs to commit or stash the changes. They’ve been edited whether by a human or not.